# Why the put method of a JSONObject throws JSONException?

Tags: java, json

I found few answers here on how to handle this exception, but there was no explanation why would this happen in the first place. I have the following code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: qosMap.entrySet()) {
        JSONObject qosEntry = new JSONObject();
        try {
            qosEntry.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JSONUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

The qosMap will never be empty, and the data in this map will always be valid.

What would be a case where the exception would thrown? Why do I need to have this extra code?

Comment: You can't put duplicate keys in JSON

Comment: @cricket_007 he is iterating through a map, so there shouldn't be any duplicate keys

Comment: you should check whether the key or value is null, since some maps support null values

Comment: @Merve The question asked why an exception would be thrown. The `put` operator knows nothing about the Map

Comment: The short answer is that `put` is defined as throwing an exception, therefore a catch is necessary. It's an implementation  detail that you  internally know it'll never reach it, so just leave it empty

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#put(java.lang.String,%20double), writing a duplicate key overwrites the existing value, not throw an exception.

Comment: Apparently `org.json.JSONObject` and `oracle.adfmf.json.JSONObject` have different rules.

Answer (score 8):

check java docs

> "If a value is a non-finite number or if a name is duplicated."

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf222/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: This is the proper answer. Duplicates will throw an error, but so will valid double values like INF and NaN, which cannot be represented in JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using `JSONObject` from [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

```
org.json.JSONObject.put(String, double) : JSONObject
```

It puts a key/**double** pair in the JSONObject.

Parameters:

key: A key **string**.
value: A **double** which is the value.

Returns: `this`

Throws:

**JSONException** If the key is null or if the number is invalid.

> I know that the data is always
>   valid. why do I need to have this extra code?

You could make the method throws the exception, as you don't like clutter up your code and also it seems you can't do anything useful by catching the exception either.

It is obvious that you know the data you passed is valid. However the library won't know. That's why it's throwing an checked exception just to let you know in case it fails.

Comment: yes, but this is point of my question I know that the data is always valid. why do I need to have this extra code?

Answer (score 1):

For all types T, JSONObject.put(String key, T value) throws a JSONException when the key is null or the value is a non-finite #. For type double, a JSONException is also thrown if the double value is invalid.
See:

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf222/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the effort by creating a simple class like this one:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ForaBolsonaroJSON {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    public ForaBolsonaroJSON put(String name, Object value) {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(name, value);
            return this;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }    
    }

    public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```